# Add multiple input values to textarea on keyup

Tags: html, jquery

I wonder if someone could please help me. I have multiple inputs that need to insert into a textarea as you type. I've gotten that to work but when I start typing in a new input it resets the textarea with only that text from the input. I need it to continuously add from each input.

```
$(responseList).on("keyup", ".response-input", function(e) {
    $("textarea").text(e.target.value);
});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure 100% about your setup and what you want to achivement in way of function but you could try something like this.

```
var t = $(".response-input").map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join(" ")
$("textarea").text(t);
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".response-input", function(e) {
  var t = $(".response-input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get().join(" ")
  
  $("textarea").text(t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="response-input" />
<input class="response-input" />
<input class="response-input" />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .append() for this. ✌️ https://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$(responseList).on("keyup", ".response-input", function(e) {
    $("textarea").append(e.target.value);
});
```

Comment: This way, what happens if I write some text inside `input.response-input#1`, then write something else in `input.response-input#2`, then go back to `input.response-input#1` to correct something (maybe a typo or completely change it)?